# Display datepicker in image location

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

How can I display the datepicker which will show it up in the image position? I am using image to trigger the datepicker.

Comment: Where will you put the date once it's selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting. The API mentions that datepicker works only on input, div and span, but I've seen some examples with a textarea.

I've used a classic input element, and formatted it to accept a background image with this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/3vrMq/).

I think this will give you a start.

CSS

```
#dp {
    height: 50px;
    width: 600px;
    background: url(http://blog.ebyline.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/copywriting-long-vs-short1.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: relative;   
}
```

JS

```
$("#dp").datepicker({
    buttonImageOnly: 'false',
        showOn: 'both',
    beforeShow: function (textbox, instance) {
            instance.dpDiv.css({
                    marginTop: 2,
                    marginLeft: 1
                                });
                                              }

     });
```